# Register an event for changing html input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, addeventlistener

Is it possible to register an event for changing html input value in javascript?

I mean I have an input. And when I type into it an event is registered, but when I update its (inputs) value through javascript the `input` event is not called. What is a workaround here?

For example, when you type into input the resulting text is updated, but when you clear the input using button (in other words through javascript) the `input` event is not registered.

html

```
<input id="inpt" oninput="updateText()" />
<div id="txtDiv">
  resulting text
</div>
<button id="btn">
Click
</button>
```

js

```
const input = document.getElementById("inpt");
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const resultingText = document.getElementById("txtDiv");
  resultingText.innerHTML = input.value;
  alet("called");
});

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value = "";
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/525/).

Comment: personnally I use the `keyup` event but it may be bad practice I don't know

Comment: but I checked your code it is working correctly.and event listener  is not registered on user input it is on Dom ready

Comment: @NullPointer, when you click the button the resulting text should become blank. It does not happen. And I did not tell that the code is not working I provided the code to explain what effect I want to achieve and what I have so far.

Comment: if you dynamically changing the value of input then you can change the innerHTML of the div also on button click.

Comment: Ok.In this case input event will not trigger implicitly and you have to do it explicit

Comment: @Chilll007, that is clearly a crutch.

Comment: @NullPointer, sounds good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that if you separate the logic in the event listener into its own function, you could just call that function when the button is pressed.

```
const input = document.getElementById("inpt");
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  changeText();
});

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value = "";
  changeText();
});

function changeText() {
  const resultingText = document.getElementById("txtDiv");
  resultingText.innerHTML = input.value;
  alert("called");
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joabysvt/1/